# como chamar uma função php através do ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

como posso chamar minha função `PHP` pelo `ajax` quando ocorrer um click no meu `span`? não estou conseguindo chamar a função corretamente alguem poderia me ajudar?

codigo `HTML`

```
<span  id="link" class="dropdown-toggle icone">
    <i class="icon-logout"></i>
</span>
```

codigo `PHP`

```
function logout($sessao){
        if($sessao == $_SESSION['logado']){
            unset($sessao);
            session_destroy();

        }else if($sessao == $_SESSION['logadoCliente']){
            unset($sessao);
            session_destroy();

        }
    }
```

codigo `Ajax`

```
$("#link").click(function(){
                $.ajax("functions/logout.php",{

                }).done(function(){

                }).fail(function(){

                });
            });
```

Comment: Essa url  "functions/logout.php" está correta ?

Comment: sim esta correta

Comment: Então qual é o problema? Já experimentou colocar um `alert` em `.done` ou `.fail` para ver se a requisição conseguiu acessar o arquivo.

Comment: Posta o código PHP inteiro. Ou esse é o código todo. Por que se for, ta ai o problema.

Comment: este e o código inteiro. isso e uma função eu quero chamar a função `logout` que esta em `functions/logout.php` quando eu clicar no span com o `id click`

Comment: Primeiro que você não está chamando a função em nenhum lugar do código PHP. Nada difere um código PHP que executa quando é invocado via browser de um código invocado via AJAX. Portando, definir uma função e nunca chama-la, vai fazer com que ela nunca seja executada. Segundo, a função está requisitando um parâmetro `$sessao`, que não está sendo fornecido pela requisição e nem definido no código.

Comment: e dai que vem minha pergunta onde eu vou chamar essa função com o `ajax` por isso fiz a pergunta

Comment: Vamos por partes. O que é $session? é o id do usuário? você tem ele no JavaScript?

Comment: De onde vai vir esse parâmetro $session? Parece um logout, será que precisa de um ajax para fazer um simples logout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> como chamar uma função php através do ajax?

**Resposta**: O `ajax` não chama a função em si, ele apenas faz a requisição para o script *logout.php*. O script `PHP` é que deve instanciar a própria função e devolver uma resposta:

*logout.php*:

```
if(isset($_GET['session'])){$sessao = $_GET['session'];} else{$sessao = '';}

function logout($sessao){
  if($sessao == $_SESSION['logado']){
   unset($sessao);
   session_destroy();
  }
  else if($sessao == $_SESSION['logadoCliente']){
   unset($sessao);
   session_destroy();
  }
}
//The cat's leap: Chame a função aqui mesmo:
logout($sessao);
```

**Obs:** eu estou supondo que o valor dessa `$session` deve ser enviado pela requisição `ajax`, então:

```
$(function () {
    $("#link").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"assets/teste.php",
            type:'get',
            data: {
                'session':'Valor da session'
            }
        }).done(function(resp){
            $( "#link" ).append( resp );
        }).fail(function(){
            $( "#link" ).append( 'Requisição falhou!' );
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Se tu fores como eu, ou seja, não goste de jQuery e não usa ele nem se te pagar, aqui tem uma outra forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function ajaxObj(meth, url) {
var x;
try {x=new XMLHttpRequest();}
catch(e) {var XmlHttpVersions=new Array("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.5.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP");for (var i=0; i<XmlHttpVersions.length && !x; i++){try { x=new ActiveXObject(XmlHttpVersions[i]);} catch (e){}}
};
if (!x){displayError("Erro ao criar o objeto XMLHttpRequest.");} else {x.open(meth, url, true);x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); x.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");x.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");x.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");return x;}};
function ajaxReturn(x){if(x.readyState==4 && x.status==200){return true;}
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function _(x){ return document.getElementById(x);}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function pc(oquepost,pagesc){
if(typeof(oquepost) !== 'undefined'){
var name = oquepost;
}else{
var div1 = document.getElementById('artigo');
var name = div1.getAttribute("data-postid");
};
if(typeof(pagesc) !== 'undefined'){var pagec = pagesc;} else {var pagec = null;};

var vars = 'procuraralgo='+name+'&pagina='+pagec;
var url = "arquivo_procurador.php";
var ajax = ajaxObj("POST",url,true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
var return_data = ajax.responseText;
_("artigo").innerHTML = return_data;}
};
ajax.send(vars);
_("artigo").innerHTML = "A processar os dados...";
}
</script>
```

Espero que ajude!

Answer (score 0):

Você clica no span e nada acontece? É isso?

Se for esse caso, tente assim:

```
$('body').on('click', '#link', function () {

   $.ajax("functions/logout.php",{

            }).done(function(){

            }).fail(function(){

            });

});
```

Seu codigo `PHP` pode ser assim (não entendi direito a existência da função...)

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logado'])){

            unset($_SESSION['logado']);
            session_destroy();

        } else if (isset($_SESSION['logadoCliente'])){

            unset($_SESSION['logadoCliente']);
            session_destroy();

        }
```

Isso se você quiser fazer o logout com `ajax`.